# How does Java distinguish between a file inside the Web Project root directory and a file which is outside the same?

Tags: java, file, tomcat

Suppose I want my Java application to read a csv/txt file; and perform some operations on the same. If I add this file inside the project (for that matter, anywhere where the classpath is pointing to), even the UI layer (.js, .html file) can read it directly. But if the same file is outside this directory and somewhere else on the host then I need to use Java IO libraries and read the file through its APIs.

I need to know what Java does behind the scenes to distinguish between the two? If the file is placed inside the project's root folder and after the project is deployed, will the application be aware of the changes done to this file or it just copies the contents of the file at the time of deployment?

Can you please also tell me what is the most apt way to read a file which is in some directory in some other logical drive. (e.g. D:/foo/bar.txt) while my application is in some other drive (C:/apache-tomcat-8.x.x/webapps/MyApplication). This file would be populated by some other application and is changing sporadically. My Java application should load the very recent file.